# Android NumberPicker error in 3.x

Tags: android, user-interface

NumberPicker shows up fine, until I try and programmatically set any of the values.  I get a NoSuchMethodException when I try and setMinValue, setMaxValue, or setValue. Any ideas?

```
this.picker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.picker);
picker.setMinValue(1);
picker.setMaxValue(500);
picker.setValue(count);
```

picker's not null, Eclipse is giving me valid intellisense and it works fine (with the exception of not having any numbers showing...) if I remove all three of the 'set' calls.

I'm targeting API v11.

Comment: Are you sure the device you're testing on is running API 11+ (3.0+)?

Comment: relevant chunk of the manifest:  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
            android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>

Comment: In that case unless you have some special casing around that code, any device under API 11 is going to crash when running this code.

Comment: Good to know, but that still doesn't explain why the emulator running Android 3.2 is throwing the error I described.

Comment: Are you sure you are *building* against API 13 though? What's in the manifest doesn't necessarily match your build settings. In Eclipse, right click your project, select properties, select Android, then make sure your Project Build Target is set to Android 3.2/API 13.

Comment: Yeah, build target is 13, but I was mistaken on the emulator; I have several setup and I was apparently clicking on the API 10 one (2.3 vice 3.2...).  Put your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the build target and device you're testing on is API 11+.